# Reading Hindi (Devanagari) on Windows XP SP1

Tags: windows-xp

Pretty much all the text that I have read on enabling Hindi (Complex Text Rendering) involve enabling it via Regional Settings > Languages > Install files for complex script support and left to right languages (including Thai).

However, I am able to read Wikipedia without having this feature enabled. Is this normal or is this an anomaly with my Win XP SP1 CD?

Comment: SP1? dude, you really need to upgrade ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it could be because wikipedia uses unicode - which should be independant of, well, pretty much anything- you wouldn't need any specialised rendering, or other tools for that to work. Least with tamil, the default arial unicode font works.

If you want to check this if this is true, gmail has a option for typing in indic languages hidden somewhere. Enable it, and see if it works too - it uses unicode, so, if that works too, its prolly the case.